# check if the given date range is completely contained within any of the date ranges in the table

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I am working with MySql and Ef core.

I have a table "SupportItems" with StartDate and EndDate columns.
I want to check given date range is completely contained within any of the date ranges in the table.

suppose I have

```
     StartDate       EndDate
```

1. ```
    08/02/2023       09/02/20223
   ```
2. ```
     10/02/2023      23/02/2023
   ```
3. ```
     25/02/2023      31/05/2023
   ```

I want to check whether   09/02/2023 - 24/02/2023 is exists or not.
It is actually not there. I don't have 24/02/2023 is in the Db.

so query will give false as result for  09/02/2023 - 24/02/2023.

example 2 :
query will give true as result for  09/02/2023 - 23/02/2023.

How can I do above requirement in Ef code?

I did below code. It will check only for each row, not all rows.

```
var checkStartEnd = activePlans.Where(z => z.ServicePlanBudgetTypes
                   .Where(y => y.SupportItems
                      .Where(x => x.StartDate.Date <= checkRequest.ActivityStartDate && x.EndDate?.Date >= checkRequest.ActivityEndDate)
                        .Any())
                       .Any())
                      .Any();
```

How can I modify the code for my expecting scenario?

Comment: How about checking day by day? How many days can be in checkRequest date range?

Comment: For that also, I have to select one than one row and check. How can I do that?

Comment: Answer my question. How long is your range?

Comment: I couldn't say a specific range. It could be in years too.

Comment: I can propose only solution for small range. About 30-60 days. But we can postprocess filter on the client side if it is acceptable. Retrieve all applicable ranges which intersects with `checkRequest` and check adjacent records.